# How are the coordinates in an Android onTouchEvent MotionEvent based?

Tags: android, view, coordinates, touch-event

I'm wondering what are the origin point, i.e. (0, 0), of the coordinates in a MotionEvent when you touch or move across the screen in Android? I know getRawX() and getRawY() get the overall screen coordinates. But I'd like to know the origin point for getX() and getY().

Is it based in the absolute top left corner of the View that runs onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)? Or is it based at the top left corner of the **content** of the View? i.e. The absolute left corner of the view, plus getPaddingLeft() on the x coordinate, and getPaddingTop() on the y.

Or is it based on some other point all together?

Answer (score 0):

GetX() and GetY() give the coordinates relative to the top-left of the view that handles the touch. Note that padding and margin are part of the view itself.